# Disabling landscape orientation programatically in swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to keep support for both landscape and portrait orientation in General - > iphone orientation. However, when the app runs, I am making a start up call and based on a flag in the response , I want to disable landscape orientation or keep it throughout the app.

How can I programatically enable or disable landscape orientation?

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller try overriding these properties like below:

```swift
override public var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

Comment: These properties are not getting called when I do so in the view controller!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may refer this apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623107-application)

As the requirement is to lock the application orientation based on the api response you can programatically handle it in the application delegate method

```
optional func application(
_ application: UIApplication,
supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
```

Comment: This is called at app start . However, the api to get supported orientation is called after user signs in and hence I need to programmatically change it at a later point